# Why does strcmp not working with Process32NextW?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mingw

I am trying to find "python.exe" in szExeFile after a `Process32NextW` call.

I tried doing a

```
if(strcmp(lppe->szExeFile,"python.exe") == 0){
    //do stuff
}
```

but the check always fails despite the process running. 
I have also tried using strncmp but it does not change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Print out szExeFile or step through with a debugger to see what it is?

Comment: This code doesn't seem like it would compile

Comment: @dav: It won't, when thrown at a C++ compiler. Since the question is tagged [tag:c], it will compile. A pointer is a pointer in C after all. You can ask for appropriate warnings, though.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All `W` versions of Win32 calls use Unicode, aka wide characters. and you have to match them: A=`char` and W=`wchar_t` wide, and you have to make all the various calls match.

The narrow way to solve this is:

```
if (wcscmp(lppe->szExeFile, L"python.exe") == 0){
    //do stuff
}
```

where `wcscmp` uses wide characters, and the `L` in front of the string makes the string of `wchar_t` instead of `char`.

But it's far better to build your code to work in Unicode with the `tchar` layer that makes it easier to build your code with ASCII or Unicode with minimal hassles.

The `UNICODE` (and `_UNICODE`) macros can be set in the project file to tell the compiler you want full 16-bit support, and with a bit of code it just works:

```
#include <tchar.h>

{
    ...
    while (ProcessNext32(...))
    {
        if (_tcscmp(lppe->szExeFile, _T("python.exe")) == 0)
        {
             // do stuff
```

Notice that `ProcessNext32` does not mention A or W; this adjusts automatically to Unicode or not.

Likewise, `_tcscmp()` is either `strcmp` or `wcscmp`, and the `_T("...")` macro puts an `L` in front of the string in Unicode mode, else not.

It's certainly some work to do this, but it doesn't take long before it becomes more natural, and your code can build properly for either way.

**EDIT**: I've considered the comments below, and they're probably right to just target Unicode directly and skip the `tchar` stuff. I've been doing this forever, and I *still* have projects that cannot target Unicode on Win32 (mainly due to old libraries and other technical constraints).

But it's a fairly heavy lift to dive fully into all of `<tchar.h>`, and - especially if you're relatively a beginner - is a waste of time and will be a source of confusion.

So: go right to Unicode and be done with it. That means `wcscmp()` and the `L` prefix will solve the issue in front of you.

Comment: Many WINAPI functions are Unicode only, regardless of whether `UNICODE` is defined, so they're not compatible with the tchar macros such as `_T`. I'm with David. Just use Unicode and let tchar become a footnote in history.

Answer (score 3):

`Process32NextW()` seems to use `PROCESSENTRY32W` struct with wide character strings. Try `wcscmp()` instead of `strcmp()`.